# PHP writing file with wrong line endings

Tags: javascript, php, python

I have some javascript code that generates a file, which then needs to be saved server side for further processing by a Python script.

My javascript creates a string, and in that string I'm using '\n' to break the lines, then I feed that string into a PHP file for saving as a text file.

my issue is when I open the file in vi, it shows ^M at the end of each line, which confuses python. I've tried getting python to generate a substring of the line without the ^M at the end, but Python won't do that.

so my javascript string looks like this when I debug:

```
line1
line2
line3
```

but the saved file looks like this:

```
line1^M
line2^M
line3^M
```

this is my javascript:

```
for(var i = 0;i < existingList.length;i++){
        console.log(existingList.options[i].value);
        saveString += existingList.options[i].value + '\n';
        }
        saveToFile(saveString);

function saveToFile(saveString){
var data = new FormData();
data.append("data" , saveString);
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open( 'post', 'savefile.php', true );
xhr.send(data);
}
```

This is my PHP:

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['data'])){
$data = $_POST['data'];
$fname = "Cards.txt";

$file = fopen($fname, 'w');//creates new file
fwrite($file, $data);
fclose($file);
}
?>
```

I've tried converting to UTF8, I've tried String.fromCharCode(13) instead of '\n' and I've tried removing the ^M in Python... any ideas?

---

**SOLUTION:**

In python I was using

```
lines = text_file.read().split('\r')
```

or:

```
lines = text_file.read().split('\n')
```

I found if you use splitlines, it automatically handles the line ending:

```
lines = text_file.read().splitlines()
```

Comment: So why do you create the file in javascript and then pass it to PHP? Why not create it in PHP?

Comment: In PHP - use `PHP_EOL` to ensure you get the 'right' version.

Comment: I'm using JavaScript because I'm more familiar with it, I've never done any PHP coding before.

Answer (score 1):

use double quotes for new line "\n" instead of '\n'

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace your line(s) of code:

`saveString += existingList.options[i].value + '\n';`

With:

`saveString += existingList.options[i].value + "\n";`

OR with:

`saveString += existingList.options[i].value + "\r\n";`

You can use `"\n"`, `"\r\n"` only as using single quotes wont work..

You can do it by editing the file or the content with `php` before you use the file, replace the content you don't want with nothing and save the file using `file_get_contents()` and `file_put_contents()`, `str_replace()` this is not pyton but you might want to try to fix it with `php` as you can do it before you use the file..

There are multiple ways to do this, this is..

`str_replace()` example:

```
<?php
/** More information regarding file_get_contents() - http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php **/
$End_Of_Line = file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/path/to/Cards.txt');

/** More information regarding str-replace() - http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php **/
$End_Of_Line = str_replace('^M', '', $End_Of_Line);
/** Or use $End_Of_Line = str_replace('^M', "\r\n", $End_Of_Line); if you need new lines.. **/

/** More information regarding file_put_contents() - http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php **/
file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/path/to/Cards.txt', $End_Of_Line);
?>
```

I hope this will bring you into the right direction

Answer (score 0):

I tested jagb's solution, and neither of them seemed to work but it got me thinking about how python reads the file. I finally found the answer:

In python I was using

```
lines = text_file.read().split('\r')
```

or:

```
lines = text_file.read().split('\n')
```

I found if you use splitlines, it automatically handles the line ending:

```
lines = text_file.read().splitlines()
```